# how to pass data/value to select option using jquery or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```
 <select id="scStatus{{sid.id}}" name="statusclass" class="selectpicker nk-int-st statusclass">
                                            <option selected value=""></option>
                                            <option value="Active">Active</option>
                                            <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
                                        </select>
```

added the select option I want to change the value using jquery or js I tried like this

```
$('.statusclass').val(data.job_status); 
 $('.statusclass').change();

 document.getElementsByClassName('statusclass')[0].value = data.job_status

           $('.statusclass option[value="' + data.job_status + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

ere

Comment: The first line of your JS should work: by setting the value of the `<select>` element will automatically mark the corresponding `<option>` as selected as long as they match. If it is not working, you might want to share an MCVE to show us what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little bit difficult to see what's wrong with the code you've got, to be honest. `.val()` should work perfectly, assuming you feed it a valid option value.

Demo (click "Run code snippet", and then click the button marked "Click to change value" to see it in action):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var data = {
      "job_status": "Active"
    };
    $('.statusclass').val(data.job_status);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="scStatus{{sid.id}}" name="statusclass" class="selectpicker nk-int-st statusclass">
  <option selected value=""></option>
  <option value="Active">Active</option>
  <option value="Suspended">Suspended</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click to change value</button>
```

Comment: I want to pass different value, not option value. for example check job_status  $(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function() {
    var data = {
      "job_status": "data"
    };
    $('.statusclass').val(data.job_status);
  });
});        data sholud show there instead of "Active"

Comment: you mean you want to add a new option to the list? Or you want to change the name of the "Active" option to something else? It's not totally clear. Give a full example of your intention. Either way, `.val()` (and all of the other code you had tried) is only able to select one option from the existing ones. It cannot modify the available options.

Comment: working now in api,active was coming like ACTIVE dts why it was not showing

Comment: Ok that's great, glad it's working. It's always good to debug your data! :-)